# How to get a specific document from QuerySnapshot in Flutter Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Guys how can i retrieve a specific document from QuerySnapshot.docs?

I once get all documents of a collection.
And after some code, i want to get a document by its ID from that collection.

I want to get that document specifically from this QuerySnapshot since i don't want to be messed with **await** later in my code.

So if i can get all documents all at once, why would i get every document one by one later with async call which would waste my time?

The thing would look like this:

```
QuerySnapshot usersSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").get();

//
//some code
//

DocumentSnapshot userDoc = usersSnapshot.docs.doc("user12345");
```

I want to get document with id **user12345**.
Is there any function like this **.doc(ID)** that i can apply on QuerySnapshot??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such method on [QuerySnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html).  You have to locate the document you want by iterating the results of the query in the [docs property](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docs.html), and check each DocumentSnapshot for the ID you're looking for.

If you want to make that easier for yourself for repeated lookups, you can iterate the docs list, and build a Map of document snapshots keyed by the ID.  Query the Map for each document you want.